# Rails Order by frequency of a column in another table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, sorting

I have a table KmRelationship which associates Keywords and Movies

In keyword index I would like to list all keywords that appear most frequently in the KmRelationships table and only take(20)

`.order` doesn't seem to work no matter how I use it and where I put it and same for `sort_by`

It sounds relatively straight forward but i just can't seem to get it to work

Any ideas?

Comment: provide more code and your code attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `KmRelationship` table has `keyword_id`:

```
top_keywords = KmRelationship.select('keyword_id, count(keyword_id) as frequency').
                              order('frequency desc').
                              group('keyword_id').
                              take(20)
```

This may not look right in your console output, but that's because rails doesn't build out an object attribute for the calculated `frequency` column.

You can see the results like this:

```
top_keywords.each {|k| puts "#{k.keyword_id} : #{k.freqency}" }
```

To put this to good use, you can then map out your actual Keyword objects:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  # other stuff

  def self.most_popular
    KmRelationship.
      select('keyword_id, count(keyword_id) as frequency').
      order('frequency desc').
      group('keyword_id').
      take(20).
      map(&:keyword)
  end
end
```

And call with:

```
Keyword.most_popular
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, the last two pieces of code seem to work, not sure what the first two are (I got undefined method for frequency). But nonetheless, the last two work.

Answer (score 0):

@posts = Post.select([:id, :title]).order("created_at desc").limit(6)

I have this listed in my controller index method which allows the the order to show the last post with a limit of 6. It might be something similar to what you are trying to do. This code actually reflects a most recent post on my home page.